# Get Token in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, token

I have this method to  get token, but i don't now how to use in Spring Boot

```
 private String getToken(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    String token = "";
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rut-stag/protocol/openid-connect/token");
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "api-stag"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", ""));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", ""));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> res = objectMapper.readValue(responseString, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
    token = (String) res.get("access_token");
    return token;
}
```

the method receives two variables

Comment: `String token = getToken("someUsername", "somePassword");`

Comment: I was thinking about a form that will show me the information